# Get density of messages on distinct ID's

Tags: python

Imagine that there is 10 houses, where there can be one to an infinite number of persons. Each of those persons sends a number of messages, containing their userid and the house number. This can be from 1 to infinite number of messages. I want to know the average number of messages that is sent by each person, for each house, to later plot which house got the largest number of average messages.

Now, that I've explained conceptually, the houses aren't houses, but latitudes, from f.ex -90 to -89 etc. And that a person can send messages from different houses.

So I've got a database with latitude and senderID. I want to plot the density of latitudes pr unique senderID:

`Number of rows/Number of unique userids` at each latitude over an interval

This is an sample input:

```
lat = [-83.76, -44.88, -38.36, -35.50, -33.99, -31.91, -27.56, -22.95,
        40.72,  47.59,  54.42,  63.84,  76.77, 77.43, 78.54]

userid= [5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 2,
         2, 2, 1, 5, 10, 9 ,8]
```

Here are the corresponding densities:

```
-80 to -90: 1
-40 to -50: 1
-30 to -40: 4
-20 to -30: 1
  40 to 50: 2
  50 to 60: 1
  60 to 70: 1
  70 to 80: 1
```

An other input:

```
lat = [70,70,70,70,70,80,80,80]
userid = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1,2]
```

The density for latitude 70 is 1, while the density for latitude 80 is 1.5.

If I would do this through a database query/pseudocode I would do something like:

```
SELECT count(latitude) FROM messages WHERE latitude < 79 AND latitude > 69
SELECT count(distinct userid) FROM messages WHERE latitude < 79 AND latitude > 69
```

The density would then be `count(latitude)/count(distinct userid)` - also to be interpreted as totalmessagesFromCertainLatitude/distinctUserIds. This would be repeated for intervals from -90 to 90, i.e `-90<latitude<-89` up to `89<latitude<90`

To get any help with this is probably a far stretch, but I just cant organize my thoughts to do this while I'm confident there are no errors. I would be happy for anything. I'm sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: If you want the solution in Python, then remove the sqlite tag.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not sure I can follow your question or code.  The density you're talking about will be defined per latitude, or range of latitude.  But the histogram you plot is binned per density.  What do you actually want to see?  I think, maybe, density per each latitude bin, but I'm not sure.  Can you confirm?  I have a solution for that if that's what you want.

Comment: @j-richard-snape Thank you for your interest. I want to plot the number of messages pr unique userid, across all latitudes. Was that clearer? Density pr latitude bin is correct i believe. If you look at my sample SQLite code, I want that for every latitude.

Comment: OK - have a go with the code in my answer and see whether it does what you want.  If so, feel free to accept / vote.  If I've mis-interpreted what you want, add a comment and I'll see if I can adapt.

Comment: If you like SQL but have reason to work in python, have you checked out pandas? Pandas doesn't use SQL syntax exactly but there's a lot of overlap, and it will also plot nicely using python libraries.

Comment: I haven't, will check out! Still appreciate any input on this case though!

Comment: Is it fair to say that `density` is (total messages)/(unique userids), per 10-degree-zone? I find `latitudes` a puzzling variable name in the output above.

Comment: Thank you for your input - I will change latitudes as total messages, as you are correct. Ideally it will be per 1-degree-zone.

Comment: isn't the first sample output missing one for the 60-to-70 zone?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I'm so sorry. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I've understood the output you want, but this will produce a stepped, cumulative histogram-like plot with the x-axis being latitudes (binned) and the y axis being the density you define above.

From your sample code, you already have `numpy` installed and are happy to use it.  The approach I would take is to get two data sets rather like what would be returned by your SQL sample and then use them to get the densities and then plot.  Using your existing latitude / userid data format - it might look something like this

***EDIT:*** Removed first version of code from here and some comments which were redundant following clarification and question edits from the OP

---

Following comments and OP clarification - I think this is what is desired:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby

def draw_hist(latitudes,userids):
    min_lat = -90
    max_lat = 90
    binwidth = 1

    bin_range = np.arange(min_lat,max_lat,binwidth)

    all_rows = zip(latitudes,userids)
    binned_latitudes = np.digitize(latitudes,bin_range)
    all_in_bins = zip(binned_latitudes,userids)
    unique_in_bins = list(set(all_in_bins))
    all_in_bins.sort()
    unique_in_bins.sort()

    bin_count_all = []
    for bin, group in groupby(all_in_bins, lambda x: x[0]):
        bin_count_all += [(bin, len([k for k in group]))]

    bin_count_unique = []
    for bin, group in groupby(unique_in_bins, lambda x: x[0]):
        bin_count_unique += [(bin, len([ k for k in group]))]        

    # bin_count_all and bin_count_unique now contain the data
    # corresponding to the SQL / pseudocode in your question
    # for each latitude bin

    bin_density = [(bin_range[b-1],a*1.0/u) for ((b,a),(_,u)) in zip(bin_count_all, bin_count_unique)]

    bin_density =  np.array(bin_density).transpose()

    # plot as standard bar - note you can put uneven widths in 
    # as an array-like here if necessary
    # the * simply unpacks the x and y values from the density
    plt.bar(*bin_density, width=binwidth)
    plt.show()
    # can save away plot here if desired


latitudes = [-70.5, 5.3, 70.32, 70.43, 5, 32, 80, 80, 87.3]
userids = [1,1,2,2,4,5,1,1,2]

draw_hist(latitudes,userids)
```

---

Sample output with different bin widths on OP dataset

[image: Output with bin widths 0.1, 1 and 10]

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I get a fair share of warnings when i run your code:

 RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  bin_density = all_in_bins * 1.0 / unique_in_bins

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  bin_density = all_in_bins * 1.0 / unique_in_bins

Comment: Thank you again, but I don't quite understand what you meant with the warning, because my programs crash and I get a various of errors: http://pastebin.com/ynAH1dK7

The list of latitudes is as long as userids, so there should always be coupled an userid with an latitude, if I understood your correctly?

Comment: There's something I didn't expect going on, with `numpy.unique` treating the list of tuples differently on the version I have installed here vs. at work. Obviously that's not a robust solution for you - so back to the drawing board for me.  I'll probably take this answer down if I can't debug it this evening - don't want to leave a flaky solution up.

Comment: As the other user commented - `pandas` is a way forward that might help you - I was originally trying to stick with the libraries you mention in the question, but you might want to explore pandas - it is very good for doing similar things to SQL but in python

Comment: Thank you, hope you still want to check out whats wrong though - probably you can just get the unique rows with set(tempuserids) - but I dont quite understand why you do it un both latitudes and userids, as its only the unique userids I want. Please tell me if I shall elaborate.

Comment: Try that. You had the same idea as me (using set to get unique).  I think I might still be getting your requirement slightly wrong though, actually.  Thinking again - I think you need to bin the entire dataset first and then make unique.  Is that right?  Have you got a small but more realistic sample data set (e.g. with some non-integer latitudes etc)?

Comment: I think you are into something there. I've updated my initial Q with some different values. Any value in range (-90,90) will do. Lets say we set the bin size at 90, i.e -90 to 0 and 0 to 90. If we got 120 different messages with latitudes between -90 and 0 with 30 different userid in these messages the  density becomes 4, and if we got 100 different messages with latitudes between 0 and 90 with 10 different userid the density becomes 10. Its basically the avg number of messages sent by an user inside an area which is at best inside 0 lat - 1 lat, 1 lat - 2 lat, from -90 to 90.

Comment: Yes - got it now.  The code above won't do that - but we can do something that will .  Basic recipe - use `numpy.digitize` to bin the data first, so you have latitude bin against userid for all rows.  Then make unique (via `set` for instance).  Then caculate density for each bin. Then plot

Comment: Thank you again, but alas I just can't make the jump from binning to calculate unique pr bin without making a code with high complexity, as I will have to reference every element in up to two lists. I've updated my question with more realistic input data - and hope you will stick with me.

Comment: Well - I have added something which should work now.  If it does what you want, please feel free to vote on it.  I think it has the advantage that you can use various bin widths including non-integer.  I'm not sure it's uber fast, or very pythonic, but it is fairly robust, I think and easy to read, I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73476/discussion-between-bjornasm-and-j-richard-snape).

Answer (score 2):

Because this packs so neatly into pandas' built-ins, it's probably fast in pandas for big datasets.

```
lat = [-83.76, -44.88, -38.36, -35.50, -33.99, -31.91, -27.56, -22.95,
        40.72,  47.59,  54.42,  63.84,  76.77, 77.43, 78.54]

userid= [5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 2,
         2, 2, 1, 5, 10, 9 ,8]
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from math import floor

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(userid,lat), columns = ['userid','lat']
)
df['zone'] = map(lambda x: floor(x) * 10,df.lat/10) # for ten-degree zones
zonewidth=10
#df['zone'] = map(floor, df.lat) # for one-degree zones
#zonewidth=1 # ditto

dfz = df.groupby('zone') #returns a dict of dataframes

#for k, v in dfz: # useful for exploring the GroupBy object
#    print(k, v.userid.values, float(len(v.userid.values))/len(set(v.userid.values))) 

p = [(k, float(len(v.userid.values))/len(set(v.userid.values))) for k, v in dfz]

# plotting could be tightened up -- PatchCollection?  
R = [Rectangle((x, 0), zonewidth, y, facecolor='red', edgecolor='black',fill=True) for x, y in p]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for r in R:
    ax.add_patch(r)
plt.xlim((-90, 90))
tall = max([r.get_height() for r in R])
plt.ylim((0, tall + 0.5))
plt.show()
```

For the first set of test data:

[image]

Comment: Interesting - could you explain what each step does? the first df set, as well as the tf['zone']? Does this actually get the density as explained?

Comment: Well, I've added code comments, but (looking severely over eyeglasses) you should have started by posting the correct output for your sample data so we'd all know if we were calculating what you'd asked for.

Comment: I really appreciate this, and I have updated my first question with two inputs alongwith correct output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves the case, allthough it isn't efficient at all:

```
con = lite.connect(databasepath)
binwidth = 1
latitudes = []
userids = []
info = []
densities = []
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT latitude, userid FROM dynamicMessage')
    con.commit()
    print "executed"
    while True:
        tmp = cur.fetchone()
        if tmp != None:
            info.append([float(tmp[0]),float(tmp[1])])
        else:
            break
    info = sorted(info, key=itemgetter(0))
    for x in info:
        latitudes.append(x[0])
        userids.append(x[1])
    x = 0
    latitudecount = 0
    for b in range(int(min(latitudes)),int(max(latitudes))+1):
        numlatitudes = sum(i<b for i in latitudes)
        if numlatitudes > 1:
            tempdensities = latitudes[0:numlatitudes]
            latitudes = latitudes[numlatitudes:]
            tempuserids = userids[0:numlatitudes]
            userids = userids[numlatitudes:]
            density = numlatitudes/len(list(set(tempuserids)))
            if density>1:
                tempdensities = [b]*int(density)
                densities.extend(tempdensities)
    plt.hist(densities, bins=len(list(set(densities))))
    plt.savefig('latlongstats'+'t'+str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")), format='png')
```

Answer (score 0):

What follows is not a complete solution in terms of plotting the required histogram, but I think it's nevertheless worthy of being reported

1. The bulk of the solution, we scan the array of tuples to select the ones in the required range and we count

   - the number of selected tuples
   - the unique ids, using a trick consisting in creating a set (this discards automatically the duplicates) and computing its numerosity

   eventually we return the required ratio or zero if the count of distinct ids is zero

   ```
   def ratio(d, mn, mx):
       tmp = [(lat, uid) for lat, uid in d if mn <= lat < mx]
       nlats, nduids = len(tmp), len({t[1] for t in tmp})
       return 1.0*nlats/nduids if nduids>0 else 0
   ```
2. The data is input and assigned, via `zip`, to a list of tuples

   ```
   lat = [-83.76, -44.88, -38.36, -35.50, -33.99, -31.91, -27.56, -22.95,
          -19.00, -12.32,  -6.14,  -1.11,   4.40,  10.23,  19.40,  31.18,
           40.72,  47.59,  54.42,  63.84,  76.77]
   userid= [52500.0, 70100.0, 35310.0, 47776.0, 70100.0, 30991.0, 37328.0, 25575.0,
            37232.0,  6360.0, 52908.0, 52908.0, 52908.0, 77500.0,   345.0,  6360.0,
             3670.0, 36690.0,  3720.0,  2510.0,  2730.0]
   data = zip(lat,userid)
   ```
3. preparation of the bins

   ```
   extremes = range(-90,91,10)
   intervals = zip(extremes[:-1],extremes[1:])
   ```
4. actual computation, the result is a list of `float`s that can be passed to the relevant `pyplot` functions

   ```
   ratios = [ratio(data,*i) for i in intervals]
   print ratios
   # [1.0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0]
   ```