# How to avoid memory error in python when retrieving from database

Tags: python, sqlite

When I try to run my code with a large amount of data, I get a memoryerror in the `all_rows = [[x[0], x[1]] for x in cur]`. I have 200M rows. How can I avoid it?

```
binwidth = 1
latitudes = []
userids = []
info = []
densities = []
with lite.connect(databasepath) as con:
    cur = con.execute('SELECT latitude, userid FROM dynamicMessage WHERE latitude>45')
    print "executed"
    all_rows = [[x[0], x[1]] for x in cur]
    all_rows = sorted(all_rows, key=itemgetter(0))
    print "sorted"
    for x in all_rows:
        latitudes.append(x[0])
        userids.append(x[1])
    min_lat = -100
    max_lat = 100
    binwidth = 1

    bin_range = np.arange(min_lat,max_lat,binwidth)

    binned_latitudes = np.digitize(latitudes,bin_range)
    all_in_bins = zip(binned_latitudes,userids)
    unique_in_bins = list(set(all_in_bins))
    all_in_bins.sort()
    unique_in_bins.sort()

    bin_count_all = []
    for bin, group in groupby(all_in_bins, lambda x: x[0]):
        bin_count_all += [(bin, len([k for k in group]))]

    bin_count_unique = []
    for bin, group in groupby(unique_in_bins, lambda x: x[0]):
        bin_count_unique += [(bin, len([ k for k in group]))]

    bin_density = [(bin_range[b-1],a*1.0/u) for ((b,a),(_,u)) in zip(bin_count_all, bin_count_unique)]

    bin_density =  np.array(bin_density).transpose()

    # all_in_bins and unique_in_bins now contain the data
    # corresponding to the SQL / pseudocode in your question

    # plot as standard bar - note you can put uneven widths in as an array-like here if necessary
    plt.bar(*bin_density, width=binwidth)
    plt.savefig('latlongstats'+'t'+str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")), format='png')
```

Comment: Append to a file instead of a list

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis Thank you - I've now added the rest of the code - how would I avoid having memory error when I later have to access the code?

Comment: First of all, try to leave the sorting to the database. It's quite good at it (hint: use SQL  `ORDER BY` clause). The same is most likely true for the bin sorting (search for SQL `GROUP BY` clause).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sadly the memory error happens long before that. The thing is that I have to use such a small bin size that I've discarded user SQL, but as I now see I should maybe chunk up my query in bits to use best of both worlds. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165972/get-density-of-messages-on-distinct-ids).

Comment: You should install the `memory_profiler` package and test your code to see which part is using up all your memory.

Comment: The memory error happens *before* the SQL statement gets executed? Because I see various copies of the data created afterwards, e.g. `len([ k for k in group])`, which is the same as `len(group)` only it creates an intermediate list.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear - I meant that the memory error happened before the sort function. Thank you for the tip!